# How to check a regex match with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, function, validation

I get this warning:

> Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /Users/mac/Sites/Database/FTTLDatabase/functionLibrary.php on line 116

With this PHP validation code:

```
function validateCardSelect($cardType)
    { // CARD TYPE ***
        if(preg_match('Please choose', $cardType))
                        {
                        return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        return true;
                        }
    }
```

All my other regular expressions work but in this case, it is a select box and doesn't work :(

Comment: That's not a regular expression. Regexs start and end with a delimiter, usually `/` - pretty much what that error message says.

Comment: What you are doing is, I'd say, incorrect. I suppose `Please choose` is the message you display by default. So what makes you think that if the sent value is not equal to `Please choose` is a valid value? You should have a list of acceptable values and compare to that instead.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Good point, I didn't even check the logic of the code, I just recognized the Warning. I guess there's 2 problems.

Comment: no need to use a regex for a simple string. if you are looking one value just do `$cardType === 'Please choose'`

Comment: @Class we're not told if $cardType contains any other text, it may or may not work.

Comment: Incidentally, if you are planning to handle actual payment card numbers, please don't. You should only do this if you are an expert in online security - it should be deferred to third-party payment handlers who can take care of it for you.

Comment: Please stop doing this pattern `if(a) return false; else return true;` `return !a` is far more better.

Comment: @alkino smart and neat note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a delimiter around your regex, such as `/` see below:

```
function validateCardSelect($cardType)
    { // CARD TYPE ***
        if(preg_match('/Please choose/', $cardType))
                        {
                        return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        return true;
                        }
    }
```

Edit: Although this answers your initial problem, please read the comments to your question.
It appears as if your logic is incorrect and as others have stated, security could be an issue.